# Eclipse CDT: fatal error: NewLib/MathFuncsLib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

## include "NewLib/MathFuncsLib.h"

The include file exists in "D:\c++\workspace\NewLib".
NewLib is another project.
I have done the configuration:

**Under Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Libraries, I've already added the include directory "D:\c++\workspace\NewLib\MathFuncsLib.h".**

**Under Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Libraries, I've already added the include directory "${workspace_loc:/NewLib/}"**

**Under Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Library Path, "D:\c++\workspace\NewLib"**

**Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > References,"NewLib" is selected.**

But the error is there:
fatal error: NewLib\MathFuncsLib.h: No such file or directory  #include "NewLib\MathFuncsLib.h"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified path to folder where `"NewLib"` resides. Because your header reads `"#include "NewLib\MathFuncsLib.h"`

So you need to specify `D:\c++\workspace` in your path.

Comment: you mean like this ?#include "D:\c++\workspace\NewLib\MathFuncsLib.h"?

Comment: thanks , question solved. but i did configure the path in Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Library Path, so what does this configuration do?

Comment: Either that in your source code OR in "Paths and Symbols" specify `D:\c++\workspace`

Comment: Yes that's more appropriate than changing paths in code.